# Performance improvement - Yii2 Eager loading

Tags: php, yii2

We have a table called content and size of table is over 5Gb. Our Yii2 backend application has a section to view those content and there are few filters available to filter out contents. I need to filter contents which are assigned or not assigned to categories.

**Relations**

A Content can be shared within many categories. So there is a one to many relationship between Content and Category tables.

Mapping table is content_cat_xref.

Models are as follows.

**Content model**

```
 /**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getContentCatXrefs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ContentCatXref::className(), ['content_id' => 'id']);
}
```

**Content_cat_xref model**

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Content::className(), ['id' => 'content_id']);
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new \common\models\ContentSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchMedia(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    ]); 
}
```

**ContentSearch Model**

```
public function searchMedia($params)
{
    $query = Content::find()->where(['file_type_id'=>[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,11]]);
    
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    
    $this->load($params);
    
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }
    
    //Conditionally add filters
    if(isset($this->is_category_available) && $this->is_category_available === 'yes'){
        $query = $query->joinWith(['contentCatXrefs' => function($queryw){
            $queryw->andWhere(['is not', 'content_cat_xref.category_id', new \yii\db\Expression('null')]);
        }]);
    }else if(isset($this->is_category_available) && $this->is_category_available === 'no'){
        $query = $query->joinWith(['contentCatXrefs' => function($queryw){
            $queryw->andWhere(['is', 'content_cat_xref.category_id', new \yii\db\Expression('null')]);
        }]);
    }
    
    if(!is_null($this->file_name) && !empty($this->file_name)) {
        $query->andWhere("MATCH (file_name) AGAINST (\"".$this->file_name."\" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)");
    }
    
    if(!is_null($this->file_path) && !empty($this->file_path)) {
        $query->andWhere("MATCH (file_path) AGAINST (\"".$this->file_path."\" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)");
    }
    
    $query->andFilterWhere(['type_code'=>$this->type_code]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['file_type_id'=>$this->file_type_id]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['content.active_status'=>$this->active_status]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['content.content_status'=>$this->content_status]);
    
    if(is_null($this->file_name)) {
        $query->orderBy("id desc");
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

**I have few questions**

1. What should be the correct and efficient way to join two tables( content and content_cat_xref) to retrieve data. I need to filter contents which are assigned or not assigned to categories. So, I use this filter for that.

   ```
       if(isset($this->is_category_available) && $this->is_category_available === 'yes'){
       $query = $query->joinWith(['contentCatXrefs' => function($queryw){
           $queryw->andWhere(['is not', 'content_cat_xref.category_id', new \yii\db\Expression('null')]);
       }]);
   }else if(isset($this->is_category_available) && $this->is_category_available === 'no'){
       $query = $query->joinWith(['contentCatXrefs' => function($queryw){
           $queryw->andWhere(['is', 'content_cat_xref.category_id', new \yii\db\Expression('null')]);
       }]);
   }
   ```
2. I use eager loading to improve performance here. But It gives duplicate records when joining these two tables. After I use distinct then it reduce the performance. What should be the correct way to do this Yii2?
3. Is there are way to pass params to relation functions when constructing query in content search model?
4. If we order content by id descending, again reduce the performance.

It is highly appreciated if there is anyone who can provide guidance on this.

Comment: You can use [andFilterWhere()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#andFilterWhere()-detail) to avoid checking empty filters.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Thanks. I replaced andWhere with andFilterWhere. 2nd issue is not fixed from it. If I use distinct() in $query it hang on until I restart the server. It happens only on server which has over 5Gb contents. Everything working fine if I use any code in my local server

Comment: @InsaneSkull Updated the post

Answer (score 1):

1. If the goal is to filter contents which are assigned or not assigned to categories, I will suggest to maintain a flag in "content" table. Or you can add index in existing tables to improve the performance on join and conditions, but it will be always slower than the condition on a flag field on a single table. You can use "explain" statement to get the information about the indexes used nd also it will be helpful to you to add new index
2. Issue is not with Yii2 but will the records maintain in the tables. If you have multiple entries in "content_cat_xref" table for a respective row from "content" table, then your join will return multiple records, where records from "content" table will be same for respective row but records from "content_cat_xref" will be different for each row. Solution is to use subquery (will effect the performance) or maintain the flag as explained in point 1
3. In Yii2, relations are formed based on method return in model class. You can write conditions in that methods. e.g.:

> ```
> if($this->is_category_available == 'yes') {
> return $this->hasMany(ContentCatXref::className(), ['content_id' => 'id'])
>         ->andOnCondition(['a_type' => 1]);
> }
> else  {
> return $this->hasMany(ContentCatXref::className(), ['content_id' => 'id'])
>         ->andOnCondition(['a_type' => 0]);
> }
> ```

4. Add indexes in your table

Comment: 1. I appreciate your suggestion. I think it will improve the performance for my current requirement. I will apply it. 
2. Currently I'm using indexes in both tables. 
3. Is there anyway to parse parameters to search model functions(relations)
4. Column 'id' is already an index

Comment: Using single column index will not improve the performance, use compound index instead. [Please follow this link for more info](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/index-merge-performance). I am not sure what you mean by using parse parameters to search functions, but you can assigning the value to member variable of the model and use that variable in relation function as shown in example.

Comment: Also note: Use EXPLAIN to figure out if and what indexes your queries are currently using & use index hints (USE INDEX, FORCE INDEX) if necessary to help MySQL optimizer to choose correct index

Comment: Ignore above comment for 3rd question. I'm trying to ask this. In content search model we are using joinWith() function with relation, contentCatXrefs. Relation is in content model. If we can pass filter params to relation we can reduce number of records when joining these two tables. Currently I'm filtering using where clause. But if we can add conditions to ON when joining, I think we can reduce records more. What do you think?

Comment: To add more conditions to ON, you can use "onCondition", "andOnCondition" or "orOnCondition"  in relation. Please refer to given example.